# To Update the new password in the database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i have successfully done the Firebase auth and link the Firebase auth with Firebase database. Now I'm working on the forgot screen I'm getting the mail regarding the password change. It is successfully changing the password. But I want to show that updated password in the Firebase database.

```
   firebase.database().ref('sevenup-a1db1/'+ 
    firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({

                password,
            })
```

I have done this but I'm getting the following: error `Reference. update failed:First argument conatins Undefind in property 'sevenup-a1db1/-hwebfkhfyegfgyu23f.password`'

```
    onResetPasswordPress = (email,password) => {
    firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email)
    .then (() => {
    firebase.database().ref('sevenup-a1db1/'+ 
     firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({
      password,
      })

        },
```

I want to update the Password in firebase database

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: you're passing `undefined` as the value to the database. So that means that `password` is `undefined` in the code you shared. This means that you're not passing a `password` parameter value into the call to `onResetPasswordPress`. It's impossible to say why that is from the code you shared.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what could be the possible answer then.

Comment: Since we don't see how you call `onResetPasswordPress`, it's impossible to say more than that you're not passing in a second parameter, or are passing in a variable whose value is `undefined`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen    <Button style={{ 
         marginTop:30
        }}  title="Reset Password" onPress={this.onResetPasswordPress} />

Comment: This is how i'm passing the on Reset method

Comment: Please add that information to your question. But from a quick scan it seems like you're not passing anything to `onResetPasswordPress`, which would explain the error. You might want to `console.log()` both parameters in `onResetPasswordPress` to verify that, and then search for [how to pass parameter to a event handler in React](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pass+parameter+to+a+event+handler+in+React).

Comment: I did the console it is showing blank that means the password is not passing there.

Comment: I do not recommend storing the plain text password in an additional database.  There is no value in that. Firebase Auth already stores it for you using best industry practices (hashing password and salting). Firebase Auth also provides a mechanism to export the hashed passwords for all your users.

Comment: No i don't want to store the password i just want to update the new password in the firebase databse.